# How can I use cache with mongdb. I use cimongo library

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I use this library in my project : [cimongo](https://github.com/vesparny/cimongo-codeigniter-mongodb-library).
Are there any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but I guess that if you find a way to identify each request using sha or md5 or some checksum, you can use this checksum as a unique key to your cache, and then store the result of the query under this key. It would be pretty straigthforward with apc.

```
<?php
$query = array("name" => "foo");
$queryHash = hash_func($query);
if (apc_exists($queryHash)){
     //If datas are already stored in apc
     $data = apc_fetch($query_hash)
} else {
     //Fetch data from DB
     $data = $db->getCollection("collectionName")->find($query);
     //Store them in apc; with a ttl of 60sec
     apc_store($queryHash, $data, 60);
}
//do stuff with $data
```

Here is the [APC user cache doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apc.php)